# Finding out just the numeric part from string and storing it as decimal datatype

Tags: sql, patindex

I tried using patindex to find the starting of the number value in a string. My goal is to just extract the numeric part from the string excluding the %.

With the below query, here are my results :

Select Column_Desc, 
Replace(substring([Column_Desc], PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [Column_Desc]), len([Column_Desc])),'%','') as New_Value

Column_Desc

1. My tax rate is 18.8% **.
2. 13.8% is my tax rate.
3. My tax rate 15.9% What is yours  ?

New_Value

1. 18.8
2. 13.8 is my tax rate.
3. 15.9 What is yours?

So, the result(New_Value) should be 18.8, 13.8 and 15.9 with a datatype of decimal. I am unable to get it to work. Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can be only one such number in a string and if it always starts with a digit (i.e. there are no values omitting the 0 before the decimal like `'.75'`) and ends with a digit, you can find the first digit by applying `patindex()` to the string (as you already do) and the last digit by applying `patindex()` to the `reverse()` of the string.

```
SELECT convert(decimal(3, 1),
               substring(column_desc,
                         patindex('%[0-9]%',
                                  column_desc),
                         len(column_desc)
                         - patindex('%[0-9]%',
                                    column_desc)
                         - patindex('%[0-9]%',
                                    reverse(column_desc))
                         + 2)) new_value
FROM elbat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8d92274712a4abde61b98ca86784dd97)

Comment: Thanks! This worked but I have some test scenarios where it did not work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=e1393a1b7f77fe3dd64de3384cf1a039

Comment: @NepaliBalak: Well, I clearly wrote, that this needs that there's only one number in the string...

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a Percent sign after the numerics, you might try the following, and then convert or cast the result into decimal.

```
Select 
    Column_Desc 
    ,Replace(
            substring([Column_Desc], 
                    PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [Column_Desc]), 
        len([Column_Desc]))
        ,'%','') as New_Value
    ,PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [Column_Desc])  as pat_Value
    ,PatIndex('%[%]%', [Column_Desc])  as pct_Value
    ,SUBSTRING(
        [Column_Desc],
        PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [Column_Desc]),
        PatIndex('%[%]%', [Column_Desc]) - PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [Column_Desc]) 
        ) as result_Value

From patindex
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you just the number before a % sign as a decimal. You'd need to validate that % exists in the predicate.

Select CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING(Column_Desc,LOCATE('%',Column_Desc)-4,LOCATE('%',Column_Desc)-1)) AS DECIMAL(3,1))

In your question you show a result as:
13.8 is my tax rate.
If that's one field it has to be a text field of some sort. Then you are just better of replacing the % with a ''

Answer (score 0):

Your in your examples the numbers are all exactly 4 characters long.  If this is always true, then the simplest method is:

```
select Column_Desc,
       convert(decimal(5, 1),
               left(stuff(Column_Desc, 1,
                          patindex('%[0-9]%', Column_Desc) - 1, ''), 4)
              ) as new_value
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c97df9a8c1a7447066241e12a5170a04).

SQL Server does not have very good string processing functions.  So, being able to make such assumptions about the string that you are looking for simplifies the code.